# Is there any way to aggregate the top n results in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have an a very large database containing data of million of products. In Elastic Search I have restricted my query to return the top 1000 results and I wan to aggregate those 1000 results. Is there any way to do it? I am been trying this from the last week? Haven't find any solution.Here's my query.

```
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 1000,
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'should' => [
                [
                    'match_phrase' => [
                        'name' => [
                            'query' => $searchQuery,
                            'boost' => 5
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'match' => [
                        'name' => [
                            'query' => $searchQuery,
                            'fuzziness' => "AUTO",
                            "operator" => "or",
                            'boost' => 3
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
      'aggs' => [    
            'company' => [
                 'terms' => [
                     'field' => 'company.raw'
                   ] 
            ]
    ]




    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 1000,
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'should' => [
                [
                    'match_phrase' => [
                        'name' => [
                            'query' => $searchQuery,
                            'boost' => 5
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'match' => [
                        'name' => [
                            'query' => $searchQuery,
                            'fuzziness' => "AUTO",
                            "operator" => "or",
                            'boost' => 3
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
      'aggs' => [    
            'company' => [
                 'terms' => [
                     'field' => 'company.raw'
                   ] 
            ]
    ]
```

Ignore the syntax. I am using some package.. I want to aggregate the top 1000 results. I want to group by company and get its count.

Comment: please show the query you have tried so far

Comment: I have posted the query below. Kindly help, I am stuck.

Comment: You should update your question instead, what you posted is not an answer ;-)

Comment: Plz give a solution

Comment: Okay updated the question. And, deleted the answer. Sir, Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? You can try it.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html